# What parameters should I pass for the schema-registry to run on non-master mode?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-schema-registry

I want to run the schema-registry in non-master-mode in Kubernetes, I passed the environment variable `master.eligibility=false`, However, it's still electing the master.

Please point me where else I should change the configuration! There are no errors in the environment value being wrong.

cmd:

```
helm install helm-test-0.1.0.tgz --set env.name.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSERVERS="PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092\,PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092\,PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092" --set env.name.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS="http://0.0.0.0:8083" --set env.name.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_MASTER_ELIGIBILITY=false
```

Details:

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
  tag: "5.0.0"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  env:
    name:
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092, PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092, PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092"
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8883"
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: localhost
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_MASTER_ELIGIBILITY: false
```

---

Pod - schema-registry properties:

```
root@test-app-788455bb47-tjlhw:/# cat /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
master.eligibility=false
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8883
host.name=xx.xx.xxx.xx
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092,PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092,PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
```

---

```
echo "===> Launching ... "
+ echo '===> Launching ... '
exec /etc/confluent/docker/launch
+ exec /etc/confluent/docker/launch
===> Launching ...
===> Launching schema-registry ...
[2018-10-15 18:52:45,993] INFO SchemaRegistryConfig values:
        resource.extension.class = []
        metric.reporters = []
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        response.mediatype.default = application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json
        kafkastore.ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        inter.instance.protocol = http
        authentication.realm =
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        kafkastore.topic = _schemas
        metrics.jmx.prefix = kafka.schema.registry
        kafkastore.ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
        kafkastore.topic.replication.factor = 3
        ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        kafkastore.timeout.ms = 500
        host.name = xx.xxx.xx.xx
        kafkastore.bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092, PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092, PLAINTEXT://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092]
        schema.registry.zk.namespace = schema_registry
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name =
        schema.registry.resource.extension.class = []
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
        compression.enable = false
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        avro.compatibility.level = backward
        kafkastore.ssl.protocol = TLS
        kafkastore.ssl.provider =
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.location =
        response.mediatype.preferred = [application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json]
        kafkastore.ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        authentication.skip.paths = []
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        access.control.allow.origin =
        ssl.truststore.location =
        ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
        port = 8081
        kafkastore.ssl.keystore.location =
        metrics.tag.map = {}
        master.eligibility = false
```

Logs of the schema-registry pod:

```
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,571] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,571] INFO Kafka commitId : 4b1dd33f255ddd2f (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,599] INFO Cluster ID: V-MGQtptQnuWK_K9-wot1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,602] INFO Initialized last consumed offset to -1 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,605] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Starting (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,715] INFO [Consumer clientId=KafkaStore-reader-_schemas, groupId=schema-registry-10.100.4.189-8083] Resetting offset for partition _schemas-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,721] INFO Cluster ID: V-MGQtptQnuWK_K9-wot1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2018-10-15 18:52:48,775] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset of the last message at 228 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,831] INFO Joining schema registry with Kafka-based coordination (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,852] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,852] INFO Kafka commitId : 4b1dd33f255ddd2f (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,909] INFO Cluster ID: V-MGQtptQnuWK_K9-wot1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,915] INFO [Schema registry clientId=sr-1, groupId=schema-registry] Discovered group coordinator ip-10-150-4-5.ec2.internal:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-10-15 18:52:49,919] INFO [Schema registry clientId=sr-1, groupId=schema-registry] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-10-15 18:52:52,975] INFO [Schema registry clientId=sr-1, groupId=schema-registry] Successfully joined group with generation 92 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-10-15 18:52:52,980] INFO Finished rebalance with master election result: Assignment{version=1, error=0, master='sr-1-abcd4cf2-8a02-4105-8361-9aa82107acd8', masterIdentity=version=1,host=ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal,port=8083,scheme=http,masterEligibility=true} (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.KafkaGroupMasterElector)
[2018-10-15 18:52:53,088] INFO Adding listener: http://0.0.0.0:8083 (io.confluent.rest.Application)
[2018-10-15 18:52:53,347] INFO jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_172-b01 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server)
[2018-10-15 18:52:53,428] INFO DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
[2018-10-15 18:52:53,429] INFO No SessionScavenger set, using defaults (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
[2018-10-15 18:52:53,432] INFO node0 Scavenging every 660000ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
Oct 15, 2018 6:52:54 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectsResource will be ignored.
Oct 15, 2018 6:52:54 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.ConfigResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.ConfigResource will be ignored.
Oct 15, 2018 6:52:54 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SchemasResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SchemasResource will be ignored.
Oct 15, 2018 6:52:54 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource will be ignored.
Oct 15, 2018 6:52:54 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.CompatibilityResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.CompatibilityResource will be ignored.
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,364] INFO HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final (org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version)
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,587] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@764faa6{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,619] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@14a50707{/ws,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,642] INFO Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@62656be4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector)
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,644] INFO Started @9700ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server)
[2018-10-15 18:52:54,644] INFO Server started, listening for requests... (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
```

Comment: What's `host=ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal` in the log? is that where your pod is running?

Comment: I am migrating the SR from mesos to k8s , the host value is one of the mesos node.

Comment: I believe it is choosing the right master. Check the answer

Comment: But when i have the same configuration running in marathon , it does not display anything like assignment of master ? why in k8s i am getting this?

Comment: That's odd, there's not really much any difference, other than this running perhaps in a cluster where your original master is.

Comment: should there be any ingress added to open port 8883 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181906/discussion-between-user-01-02-and-rico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and your configs look good. I believe, it is, in fact, starting as a follower and the logs are basically displaying who the master is in this case:

`Assignment{version=1, error=0, master='sr-1-abcd4cf2-8a02-4105-8361-9aa82107acd8', masterIdentity=version=1,host=ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal,port=8083,scheme=http,masterEligibility=true}`